# CRM JS event for field value changed by workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have form and button on that form in CRM 2015. By clicking on button on form, user triggers on-demand workflow. When workflow is done, it updates value of one of the fields on the form. However, this server data change is not reflected on the user UI.

What is the best way to register JS callback which will refresh form if workflow execution is successful?

Reading this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334701.aspx  it looks like I can't use OnChange() event, because I change data programatically.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest to use Sync Workflow. After workflow is executed just execute following code:

```
Xrm.Page.data.refresh(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had such requirements once. I had to reflect changes on the `Form` that are changed by the **Async Workflow**, and for some reason i had to keep the Workflow Async.

Following is a work-around i did for requirements like this.

Add a **new field to the entity**, on which the workflow is executed.

```
FieldName: "isworkflowexecutedsuccessfully"
FieldType: "TwoOption"
Default Value: "false"
```

Then in your code where you have written the workflow code, write this:

```
function someFunctionOfYours() {
RunWorkflow(); //
WaitForWorkflowToCompleteProcessingAndThenReload();
}

function isWorklowExecutionCompleted(TimerId, updateIsWorkflowExecutedSuccessfully) {
var entityName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();
var entityGuid = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

var retrievedOpportunity = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Retrieve(entityName, entityGuid, new Array("isworkflowexecutedsuccessfully")); //synchronous call
if (retrievedOpportunity.attributes["isworkflowexecutedsuccessfully"].value = true) {
    clearInterval(TimerId);
    setTimeout(function () {
        setIsworkFlowExecutedSuccessfullyToFalse(updateIsWorkflowExecutedSuccessfully);
    }, 3000);
}
}

function WaitForWorkflowToCompleteProcessingAndThenReload() {
var TimerId = setTimeout(function () {
    isWorklowExecutionCompleted(TimerId);
}, 5000);
}

function setIsworkFlowExecutedSuccessfullyToFalse(updateIsWorkflowExecutedSuccessfully) {
var entityName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();
var entityGuid = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

var updateOpportunity = new XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.BusinessEntity(entityName, entityGuid);
updateOpportunity.attributes["isworkflowexecutedsuccessfully"] = false;
if (updateIsWorkflowExecutedSuccessfully == false || updateIsWorkflowExecutedSuccessfully == null) {
    XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Update(updateOpportunity);
}
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(entityName, entityGuid) //refresh form
}
```